# How to fix "undefined symbol: BrotliEncoderTakeOutput" when apache start

Tags: apache, brotli

I have compiled `mod_brotli.so`, but when I restart apache, it cannot load module.

**Error :**

> httpd: Syntax error on line 155 of /usr/local/apache2/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_brotli.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_brotli.so: undefined symbol: BrotliEncoderTakeOutput

Comment: Can you edit and say how you built the module, if you used system brotli or built it yourself, etc?

Comment: updated my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same problem. I don't know if it is the *cause*... in my case we are trying to add mod_brotli to Apache 2.4.34, from the Red Hat software collection (why they don't compile it with Brotli and include the Brotli package as a dependency, I have no idea).

I am not C developer, coming from the admin side, I can't see why it isn't working.
At first I thought it was an ldconfig issue, so I added a new file to the config dir, but it still doesn't work...

```
# apachectl -M
httpd: Syntax error on line 129 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_brotli.so into server: /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_brotli.so: undefined symbol: BrotliEncoderTakeOutput
```

Here you can see that ld knows about it, and that lib has the symbol...

```
# ldconfig -p | grep brotli
libbrotlienc.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib64/brotli/libbrotlienc.so.1
libbrotlienc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib64/brotli/libbrotlienc.so
libbrotlidec.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib64/brotli/libbrotlidec.so.1
libbrotlidec.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib64/brotli/libbrotlidec.so
libbrotlicommon.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib64/brotli/libbrotlicommon.so.1
libbrotlicommon.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib64/brotli/libbrotlicommon.so

# nm /usr/local/lib64/brotli/libbrotlienc.so | grep BrotliEncoderTakeOutput
0000000000090970 T BrotliEncoderTakeOutput
```

Meanwhile, you can see the undefined symbol in mod_brotli:

```
# nm /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_brotli.so | grep BrotliEncoderTakeOutput
U BrotliEncoderTakeOutput
```

Compiling the Apache module was done with

```
apxs -i -c -I /usr/local/include/brotli/ mod_brotli.c
```

Brotli itself was compiled from the latest tarball from github...

Apache is otherwise running fine, with the brotli line commented out.

Will post again if I find the answer...

====

Edit:

I got it working (well, having issues related to haproxy and h2c (unencrypted http2), but that's another matter)

In my case, the two issues were

A) I had compiled brotli in a bad way (based on some blog posts), compiling it per the google github readme worked

B) I was compiling the module with `apxs` command, but it turns out that is only for *third party* modules. The correct way for Apache built in modules that just didn't get compiled originally is:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd --enable-brotli --with-brotli=/usr/local
```

and then `make install` (prefix is for the RH SCL version of course) (I actually did make install from the modules/filters/ dir, so it would install as little as possible as an override... not sure if it was needed, but that's what I did).

I figured out B) first, but it wasn't picking up the Brotli libs, after A) it worked fully.

I have no idea what `apxs` is doing differently, or why there should be different ways to compile modules, but hey.

I hope this will be at least some help.

Comment: I compile brotli from https://github.com/google/brotli, the other steps the same as yours.